# Conversion of type 'Promise<any>' to type 'any[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other

Tags: angular7

I'm getting this error

Conversion of type 'Promise' to type 'any[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.ts(2352)
Conversion of type 'Promise' to type 'any[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'Promise' is missing the following

service class

```
import { User } from './../models/user';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Global } from '../shared/global';
import { Question } from '../question';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
private apiUrl=Global.WEB_API_URL;
user:User[];

getQuestions():Observable<User[]>{
return this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl + '/Questions/GetAllQuestions')
.map((res:Response) =><user[]>res.json());
}


}
```

user interface

```
export interface User {
    id:number;
    question:string;
    choice:Choices[]
    }

    export class Choices{
        ChoceId:number;
        Value:string;
    }
```

Comment: Some more details on the `User` and it's usage, service and call from component would be helpful to find out the reason

Comment: @nircraft thanks, updated the question, am not calling this service in component still now, i'm going to write service now and  am getting compile error

Comment: This is happening because `res.json()` returns a promise which cannot be converted to the `User[]`. You should be mapping it to return an observable or user[]

Comment: `HttpClient.get()` applies `res.json()` automatically and returns `Observable<HttpResponse<string>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is shown because `res.json()` returns a promise which cannot be converted to the User[]. You should be mapping it to return an observable or user[] or try to resolve the promise : `return res.json().then(response => ({ response }));`

Howver you do not need to do this anymore with new Angular.
 **In Angular 7**:

`HttpClient.get()` applies `res.json()` automatically and returns `Observable<HttpResponse<any>>`

so your service call can be as below:

```
getQuestions():Observable<User[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>(this.apiUrl + '/Questions/GetAllQuestions')

}
```

You can do any mapping if needed but `res.json()` is not required.

Comment: i'm getting this error `Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User[]>'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?`

Comment: updated my answer.. You should return what is expected of the method.. in this case get call will return `<User[]>`